# ruby on rails error for navigation menu link ,using "% link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner for coding.
I am taking specific lesson,but some of action doesn't work for me.
techincally it should show "home ","about" navigation link above the page,but it doesn't work for me.

here's what it says:(it's a home.html.erb file)

`<% link_to "Home", root_path %>`

`<% link_to "About", about_path %>`

`<h1>Welcome to one month rails!</h1>`

`<p>you've found the home page for the <%= link_to "one month rails", "http://onemonthrails.com" %>
application.
</p>`

Is there anyone who could help me?

Thank you in advance

P.S:I am using windows 7 for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some equal signs:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<%= link_to "About", about_path %>
```

`<%` and `<%=` are different:

```
<% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>
```

Check [ERB Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) for details.